# Text sits behind the div elements background

Tags: html, css

I am a little confused at the minute I have this code:

HTML:

```
<div class="ms-layer ms-caption chevron">97.2%</div>
```

CSS:

```
.chevron {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px !important;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 6em;
}

.chevron:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 51%;
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
}
.chevron:after {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
}
```

Now as you can see the chevron is made up of two parts, the before and after classes.

The issue I am having is that the text I have added to the div sits behind the chevron however I want it to sit on top. I haven't really used CSS shapes before so I am a little baffled to why it isn't working.

As you can see I have made one side of the div position as absolute and the other as relative and it has made a difference but hasn't solved the problem.

Any help would be great thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code

```
.chevron:before {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 blue;
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
    width: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="ms-layer ms-caption chevron"><span>97.2%</span></div>


.chevron span {
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;   
}
```

If you don't want to change your dom structure, add `z-index:-1` to `.chevron:before`

Answer (score 1):

Use z-index:5;

Z-index will help you display anything in the front.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps add a z-index to the css for .chevon

Do you have this showing somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

have your chevron:before class behind it.

just add `z-index:-1`;

this will set the shape behind the text